# Vaadin TextArea is not cleared if using clear() or setValue("")

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I instantiated a normal `TextArea` of Vaadin with no special extras. Now in a thread I update a long string, which should be displayed within the text area. The update takes place all 5 seconds. What I do the is the following:

```
  public void setLogText(String text)
  {
    Runnable uiRunnable = () -> {
      if (logTextArea != null)
      {

        System.out.println("logTextArea");
        logTextArea.setReadOnly(false);
        logTextArea.setValue("");
        logTextArea.markAsDirty();
        logTextArea.setValue(text);
        logTextArea.markAsDirty();
        logTextArea.setCursorPosition(text.length());
        logTextArea.setReadOnly(true);
      }
    };
    UI.getCurrent().access(uiRunnable);
    UI.getCurrent().push();
  }
```

This method is called from the thread which is placed into a controller.
Now my problem is, that if I call the method `setValue("")` and I run the application in debug mode, it'll set the text to `""`. But after that I set the text to the newly one created by the thread. This new text contains the old text plus new text. What happens now, is that the text will be placed into the `TextArea` twice, three times, four times (as often as the thread runs).

I just want to have the text in there ONE time.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code snippet, from which the method `setLogTex(...)` is called:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        while (!Thread.interrupted())
        {
          try
          {
            Files.lines(Vars.LOGGING_LOG_FILE.toPath()).forEach(new Consumer<String>()
            {

              @Override
              public void accept(String t)
              {
                resultString += "\n" + t;
              }
            });

            administrationComponent.setLogText(resultString);

            Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME_MSEC);
          }
          catch (IOException e)
          {
            Log.warn(AdministrationLogController.class, "Cannot read log file.", e, administrationComponent.getSessionID());
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
            Log.warn(AdministrationLogController.class, "The read log file thread has been interrupted.", e,
                administrationComponent.getSessionID());
          }
        }
      }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Use the `synchronized` keyword in your method call

Comment: @MuratK. Nope. There IS only ONE thread, so I don't need this. I tried it, but my expectations refuted it.

Comment: Why do you use `push()` actually?

Comment: @MuratK. I tried it without some times. But it's the same.

Comment: Can you post the snippet where you call this method?

Comment: Clear your resultString variable each time your Thread runs.